# Nested SELECT in OR conditional

Tags: php, sql, mariadb

(first off sorry for bad english)

My main intention is to retrieve a search query from another table in another SELECT

here is my code if both full_name and nickname were in same table

```
if (isset($q)){
    $query = 'SELECT * from names_list WHERE full_name LIKE \'%' . $q . '%\' OR nickname LIKE \'%' . $q . '%\'';
}
```

But since they are not in same table, I would like to replace `OR nickname LIKE \'%' . $q . '%\'` to something like `OR SELECT * from nicknames_list` etc but I get an error doing it so what would be best practice to achieve that ?

Thank you

Here is names_list table example

| id | full_name | last_name | middle_name | first_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John Marc White | White | Marc | John |
| 2 | Danny Samuel Brown | Brown | Samuel | Danny |
| 3 | Bella Grey | Grey |  | Bella |

And here is nicknames_list example

| nick_id | id | nickname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | JohnJohn32 |
| 2 | 1 | Johnny32 |
| 3 | 2 | Danny12 |
| 4 | 3 | Bella1996 |
| 5 | 3 | ItsBella |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest `exists`:

```
SELECT nl.*
FROM names_list nl
WHERE nl.full_name LIKE ? OR
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM nicknames_list nnl
              WHERE nnl.id = nl.id AND
                    nnl.nickname LIKE ?
             );
```

Note that I removed `'%search_query%'` from the query.  This is quite intentional.  You should not be munging query strings with such values -- it introduces potential syntax errors that are very hard to debug and it makes the code subject to SQL injection.

You should be using parameters to pass in such values and `?` is a parameter placeholder.

Comment: If we are using `EXISTS` to find the nicknames using a subquery,  then why do we have a `LEFT JOIN` with the same table? Isn't it redundant?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it works flawlessly!
@MushifAliNawaz I have tried everything but the codes you provided kept giving me `mysqli_fetch_object() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given` errors in Postman. I guess it comes from somewhere else in my code but I haven't found a way to solve it

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem in 2 ways:

**1. `LEFT JOIN`**

You can use a `LEFT JOIN` to join both tables. And then use an `OR` condition to filter the results.

```sql
SELECT full_name, last_name, middle_name, first_name
FROM names_list
         LEFT JOIN nicknames_list ON names_list.id = nicknames_list.id
WHERE full_name LIKE '%search_query%'
   OR nickname LIKE '%search_query%';
```

**2. `UNION ALL`**

You can use `UNION ALL` operator to combine selects from multiple tables:

```sql
SELECT full_name, last_name, middle_name, first_name
FROM names_list
WHERE full_name LIKE '%search_query%'

UNION ALL

SELECT full_name, last_name, middle_name, first_name
FROM nicknames_list
         JOIN names_list ON names_list.id = nicknames_list.id
WHERE nickname LIKE '%search_query%';
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the reply, I edited my question to add a visual table
As you can see both tables are not the same at all

Comment: @Kheyonnant Thank you for providing the table information. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Kheyonnant I have updated my answer now. Do let me know if that helps?